# Gradle Duplicate class

Tags: android, gradle

When trying to use the IDnow library with the TrueLayer library Gradle fails to build due to a `duplicate class` error. The problem is that the duplicated class is bundled inside IDnow and if I try to exclude it from TrueLayer, my app fails at runtime.

```
> Duplicate class org.bouncycastle.LICENSE found in modules jetified-bcprov-jdk15to18-1.69 (org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15to18:1.69) and jetified-idnow-android-sdk-5.1.11-runtime (de.idnow.sdk:idnow-android-sdk:5.1.11)
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this in build.gradle

```html
android{
    configurations{
       all*.exclude module: 'conceal'
       all*.exclude module: 'bcprov-jdk15on'
       }
     }
```

Comment: Doing this results in RunTimeError for TrueLayer.

Comment: this helping on my case perfect answer

Answer (score 0):

Remove `jcenter()` from your gradle section.

And use the `mavenCentral()`.

Comment: Already doing this.

Comment: Add this line also `maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }`

Comment: Still the same error